# How do I hide the first line that displays the python path and the file path in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using the integrated terminal in VS Code for Python, and I want to hide the first line that shows the Python installation path and the .py file location whenever I run my code. I tried the folder hide trick that uses a $profile method but the line still displays a "& C:/User....". Any ideas? Thanks! I'm on Win 10, btw.
Here’s a picture of the terminal. I want to hide the line that starts with “
Serafin>……"

[image]

Comment: Just a comment, but I would find it doubtful you could do this without turning printing off completely at the command line.

Comment: Following for answer. I've watched Komodo Edit terminal in action and it doesn't show the first line or path, it only shows the code run. I'm hoping there is a way to do this with VS code somehow, maybe a plugin? I hope there is a solution because the path makes the terminal look very messy.